# How to get the length of a Rust HashMap<> that is wrapped in Arc<> and RwLock<>?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a simple structure with a questions variable defined as follows:

```rust
struct Store {
    questions: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<QuestionId, Question>>>,
}
```

- `HashMap<QuestionId, Question>` - *[The hashmap itself containing id and data.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)*
- `RwLock<>` - *[Preventing multiple writes to data.](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/sync/struct.RwLock.html)*
- `Arc<>` - *[Allows multiple pointers to same complex data structure.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)*

Sorry if this is a primitive question but:

**How can I get the length of the `HashMap<>` that is wrapped in `RwLock<>` and `Arc<>`?**

I could not seem to find anything in the Arc documentation either (even though I know it is not responsible for tasks like this).

For some context, this is a store intended to be used by a Rest API Web Server implemented with the [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/) framework.

Comment: Are you sure it's `std::sync::RwLock` and not `tokio::sync::RwLock`? From your answer it doesn't looks so.

Comment: Accidently linked wrong doc, fixed this in post. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: How do you do anything else with the HashMap - e.g. how do you retrieve an element from it? I assume you call `read()` on the map and then use it. You get its length in exactly the same way: `store.questions.read().await.len()`. And if your question is how to compute the length of a `HashMap` without collecting all the values, then that's a general question that has nothing to do with `Arc` and `RwLock` (and the answer is the same - call `len()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although previous answers explain *how* to get `HashMap`'s length, they do not explain *why* it works. I'll try to explain the latter, so you will understand this mechanism in the future.

Calling methods of "inner" objects on the "outer" objects is possible thanks to the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait and [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods).

`Deref` trait defines semantics of the dereferencing operator `*`. For example when you dereference `String` you get `str` and when you dereference `Vec<T>` you get `[T]`. Similarly smart pointers like `Box<T>` or `Arc<T>` give you `T` when you dereference them.

You could do this dereferencing manually:

```rust
let map = Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::from([("a", "b"), ("c", "d")])));
let len = (&*(&*map).read().await).len();
```

However this quickly gets very messy. Luckily to help comes *deref coercion* and auto-magically performs this series of dereferencing. The details of how it works are described in the linked documentation, but the gist of it is that when you call method `foo` on object `bar: Bar` the compiler will do the following:

1. check if `Bar` has method `foo`, if not then
2. check if `Bar` implements `Deref<Target=Baz>` and if it does then
3. check if `Baz` has method `foo`, if not then
4. perform steps 2 and 3 translatively for previous `Deref` `Target` until it finds type that implements method `foo`

So when you write

```rust
let len = map.read().await.len();
```

the compiler does the following:

1. Checks for method `read` on `Arc<RwLock<_>>` and doesn't find it.
2. Tries to dereference it and checks for method `read` on `RwLock<_>`.
3. It finds it, and after `await`ing result you have a `RwLockReadGuard<'_, HashMap<_, _>>`.
4. It looks for method `len` on `RwLockReadGuard<_>` and doesn't find it.
5. So it dereferences it once more and you have in result `HashMap<_>`.
6. Finally compiler finds type that implements `len` method so it calls it.

Answer (score 3):

Just like with any other `HashMap`, by calling [`len()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.len). Of course, you need to acquire a lock:

```rust
store.questions.read().await.len()
```

Answer (score 1):

> `let res: Vec<Question> = store.questions.read().await.values().cloned().collect();`

That is  inefficient, especially given the fact that `HashMap` provides a `len` method. You can condense your solution to something like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;

use tokio::sync::{RwLock};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let m = Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::from([("a", "b"), ("c", "d")])));
    
    assert_eq!(m.read().await.len(), 2);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4cdd44cee253e4663949dbc994e071d)